# What are the characteristics of a kosher flour sifter?

Tags: kashrut-kosher

there are flour sieves that are sold with rabbinical approval. You can see one here: http://cdn.instructables.com/FQ7/UKPN/FI8VJOBL/FQ7UKPNFI8VJOBL.LARGE.jpg ([archive link](https://imgur.com/XWYe92D))

What are the requirements for a kosher flour sifter? I'd like to buy one that fulfills the kosher requirements, and I don't have access to one with rabbinic approval.

Comment: Apparently, it has to be whole. (The label in the picture says, at the bottom, "one should inspect the wholeness of the sifter before use".)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [OU guide](https://www.ou.org/life/files/Kashrut_Organization_Nov13.pdf) to Kashrus in Israel says:

> White flour: In the US there are special methods used in processing
>   flour to insure that it remains bug free until use. Unfortunately in
>   Eretz Yisrael flour is not processed in the same way and insect
>   infestation can occur. Therefore it is important always to sift flour
>   before using it. You may sift more flour than you need and freeze the
>   excess. This should be done immediately. Flour that is stored in a
>   freezer immediately after sifting requires no further cleaning.
>
> **A 70 mesh sieve is recommended. These are available in most kitchen or
>   housewares stores.**
>
> Whole wheatflour: It is nearly impossible to sift whole wheat flour
>   with a 70 mesh sifter. While some poskim are lenient and allow a 50
>   mesh sieve to sift whole wheat flour, buying either frozen or vacuum
>   packed whole wheat flour with a reliable bug free hashgacha is
>   recommended. When buying frozen flour, check that the flour was kept
>   frozen.

So the criterion is 70-mesh.